# Sending SMS on phone start in android

Tags: android, sms, smsmanager

I am developing an android app where I need to send the SMS at the phone boot. I have registered receiverfor android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED and DEVICE_BOOT_COMPLETED.

My application receives above events when phone is started. However it is not sending any SMS.
I am calling following function to send SMS. It does not show any error but fails to send any SMS. I am using KitKat version. Please help.

```
public static void sendMessageString phonenumber,String message)
    {
        SmsManager manager = SmsManager.getDefault();
        manager.sendTextMessage(phonenumber, null, message, null, null);

    }
```

Please help.

Comment: have you given the permission <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SEND_SMS" /> in manifest ?

Comment: I suggest you add logging and try/catch Throwable around your call to see if something went wrong. You also might have the issue that the SIM card is not yet unlocked on boot finish.

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />

add this permission to Manifest..and also check that is your BroadCastReciever is being called or not??

Comment: Thanks everyone for inputs. I tried all above, but somehow it is not working on KitKat. Finally i tried workaround where I scheduled a timer once BroadCastReciever is invoked on start. Timer with 5 minute delay successfully sends the SMS. Looks like all applications are not initialized before BOOT COMPLETED event is recieved.